# What would stop Web3 accessing a node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using this command to start geth. Geth starts but I cannot connect to it via Web3. I get a couldn't connect to localhost. Has anyone any idea why this would happen?

> nohup geth --datadir node6/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30316 --rpc
>   --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8506  --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes
>   'enode://739f2c03c2378b1335bbdff6f8fff481339224b9bb6dccf2799a8075c450871fa40057c42c10de0703e2637514537b1a7d129177f452e9d719e7832cde55fbd7@10.154.0.2:30310'
>   --networkid 1520 --gasprice '1' -unlock 'f39995b718ae7a0075557f9781425b92fd8b28a6' --password
>   node6/password.txt --nat "any" --mine &

Comment: try putting `0.0.0.0` at the place of `localhost`

Comment: I did test that, and the same issue was there. I did also discover that 8545 is needed apparently for Web3 access via RPC. With that change I can now access the node via Web3 in node. But the Chrome access still fails.

Comment: 8545 is the default port when you didn't provide any such value, in your case 8506 will work. Can you please put some code how you are trying to access it?

Comment: I am using        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); with different port numbers.

Comment: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#providers : Trying using one of the methods mentioned here